# I need to shorten text search

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, search

I was wondering if it is possible to search for part of a text string. For example if the following is in cell A9:

```
[Agent Name & ID: Ted Simpson - 1008]
```

I am looking for a way to shorten it to

```
if(a1:a9="1008", t23, "")
```

rather than

```
if(a1:a9="Agent Name & ID: Ted Simpson - 1008", t23, "")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you be willing to develop a VBA macro?

Did a quick search for what you may want and found this at [TechGuy](http://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/729263-solved-excel-wildcard-formula.html)

Some useful links to read up on:

- [Search, SearchB - Microsoft Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/search-searchb-functions-HP010342873.aspx)
- [Find, FindB - Microsoft Office](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/find-findb-functions-HP010342526.aspx)

For what you want, you may want to use cell References, like a search box.

`=if(search(value, cell)>0, true-value, false-value)`

In your case

`=if(search("1008", A1:A9)>0, t23, "")`

Although, i would probably transform A1:A9 into a 1 column Table format or, at least, an expandable NamedRange so you can reference the Range instead of a defined Column/Row definition.

`=if(search("1008", lstAgents)>0, t23, "")`

#### Edited 2012-10-15 @ 15:21

Table/Range Design:

```
Name | ID | NameID
Ted Simpson | 1008 | =[@Name] & " - " & [@ID]
```

Now the `Name` & `ID` columns can be visually hidden and `NameID` column, and all others after, can be visual and not actively used, per say.

Comment: Oh and you will have to handle for the Error if `Search()` is not found.  Which makes me want to go more towards the VBA Macro usage than incell formula method.

Comment: when I try to use the formula I get #VALUE! rather than result (2)

Comment: I got it to work with out the quotes ""

Comment: can you tell me if search works for a range of cells? if I point to a cell A21 that contains the 1008 the formula works but if I use a range A9:A28 I get the #VALUE! error

Comment: can you give me some exaples on the named range or table format?

Comment: sorry for the delay but had a support nightmare this weekend.  Let me draw something up this afternoon and ill edit my original posting with some ideas.  As i dont know the situation or infrastructure your working with, take it with a grain of salt ;)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the functions `FIND` or `SEARCH`, I guess.

Example, not tested (in excel 2010):

```
=IF(SEARCH("1008", L6:L17,1),t32,"")
```